# Cannot connect to Azure VM with SSMS

Tags: azure

I've created a new VM in resource manager on Azure with SQL 2016 installed and am now trying to connect via SSMS from my workstation.  I have followed this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-connect#connect-to-sql-server-over-the-internet) but still receive "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred..." at this point and am not sure what else to check.  Telnet also fails on port 1433 but I can successfully RDP into the server.

Network Security Group configuration (opened all ports in desperation):
[image]

TCP/IP enabled on VM SQL Server:
[image]

DNS entry assigned.  Have left overnight in case the A record takes time to propagate?
[image]

I can successfully connect on the VM's SSMS to the local SQL server, but when I try from my remote workstation I still get:
[image]

I'm at a loss at this point for what else needs to be setup...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18060818/296861

Comment: Found the answer buried in one of the comments on that thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out what wasn't working. Buried in the comments on this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci/18060818#18060818) was:

> Also REMEMBER to ENABLE SQL Server Browser service. Have setup a
>   number of SQL servers in my time... Yet this step always seems to have
>   different scenarios involved :)

It appears that this wasn't done in the automated SQL setup via the VM installation.  I can now connect to the VM remotely with SSMS.

Comment: I had the same problem, what I should change was: 
 click on th VM in AzurePortal --> SQL Server configuration --> Change SQL Connectivity to public